# How do I save data in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

So I made sort of a Cookie Clicker app to help me start learning how to program on android, using Android Studio.
But I need a way to save the amount of cookies the player has, so when he quits the game and comes back they will be saved.
This is the code I have currently:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.android.example;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            /* Sound */
        final MediaPlayer cookieSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cookie_eat_short);

        ImageButton playCookieSound = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.cookie_button);

        playCookieSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cookieSound.start();
                /* End of Sound */

                /* The following lines add 1 to the score and then display it. */
                scoreCookies++;
                display(scoreCookies);
            }

        });

    }

    /*  Initializing the score to 0
    * This is also what I want to change, make it set the score to the saved score.*/
    int scoreCookies = 0;

    /* This method displays the score on the screen. */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cookie_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cookiepic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="42sp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />
```

Thanks in advance for helping me :)

Comment: Please just look at Google or another search engine. There are at least 50000 articles about it.

Comment: you should read this [SharedPref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Shared Preferences to save a small amount of data.

**Write**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

**Read**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```